# Faster way to reject queries with Quarkus Rest Easy

Tags: quarkus

I am implementing a REST endpoint using reactive approach with Quarkus REST easy.  We need to implement "overload protection" for the microservice that in our case translates to the need to reject operation with error code 503 in order to allow that microservice is able to keep running (e.g. with OoM execeptions), and being able to answer part of the traffic under a latency budget. To do that, we have an external client monitoring latency of the REST endpoint and providing feedback to the microservice with a hint of the percentage of queries that can be rejected.

We test our microservice in conditions that it receives for instance (nominal capacity) x 10 and is expected to keep running, reject a high number of operations (e.g. 9x%) and answer some amount with a decent latency). Internally we are already using BulkHead and RateLimit in some of our methods in the REST endpoint, but when doing that the entity that is deserialized in JSON has already been deserialized and that is something that could have been avoided to save CPU / memory

I would like to know what the cheapest way is to reject operations in terms of using the minimum number of resources.

As of today, we are rejecting operations using a Vertx Reactive Route to do that.

```
  @Route(methods = HttpMethod.POST, path = "/query")
  public void post(RoutingContext rc) {
    if (!ThreadLocalRandom.instance.nextInt(99) < rejectLevel) {
          rc.response().setStatusCode(503).end("Overload")
    } else {
      rc.next();
    }
  }
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this in an earlier stage to avoid processing?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to implement this:

1. the handler in vert.x web that limit the concurrency - that's your approach
2. use ngnix in front (you can implement the nginx health mechanism)
3. wait for the complete integration of the next version of vert.x (as we need new config) - this will allow traffic shaping (see https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/6c80b1e9fcfab18b01c0de8a00009b515bd3fe4e/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/net/TrafficShapingOptions.java)

You can already use (3) if you use a Vert.x customizer (https://quarkus.io/guides/vertx-reference#customizing-the-vert-x-configuration) and set the traffic shaping options.

Comment: My bad, you cannot configure traffic shaping - it's not in Vert.x 4.4. It will be in 4.5 or 5.x